# Vim and Tmux doens't fit with each other

Tags: vim, tmux

My colors breaks on tmux and i tried almost everything i could find on the web, NONE of them should actualy solve this problem.

This is my colors inside tmux

[image]

im using the default vim theme but all themes are broken inside tmux, and that file is my .tmux.config, i try a lot of different solutions none of them change a thing.

This is what should like

[image]

My themes works fine without tmux, but the theme change inside tmux is not just annoying literaly set in bad colors that compromises my use of both tools together.

My terminal is x-terminal-emulator and i use zsh.

Comment: What is `echo $TERM` inside tmux? How about outside tmux? What happens if you use something like `export TERM=screen-256color` inside tmux? Try starting tmux with `tmux -2` to see if that changes anything?

Comment: I tried those two, for real i didn't find any answer to this...
Rigth now i can't do this test's again but yes i done all those things you say, i really tried to match things up, start tmux with -2 and all.
I'm not using xterm anymore for preference matters i was testing the terminal but i really always liked the gnome-terminal and i go back to it(and vim works fine inside and outside tmux), i dont go back only because this issue i just like gnome-terminal more, i will let this topic open for those who have the same issue and if some different answer cames i will try to test.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what `echo $TERM` (in the shell) and what `:set term?` (in Vim) shows inside and outside tmux. Also `:set t_Co?` inside Vim. That should help us diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The default  `tmux` configuration file should be `~/.tmux.conf` and not `~/.tmux.config`.

Make sure to source the config file too. From outside of `tmux` and from your shell:

```
tmux source ~/.tmux.conf
```

Then open `tmux` back up and hopefully it's loaded correctly.

Tip:

Always restart `tmux` with theme applications; it often hangs if you opt to use the `[crtl+b]+i` keyboard shortcut of `tmux` default command list whilst within it to reload the config.